# how to access a file in the application folder from a model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I delete a file that resides in a child folder of Codeigniter's `/application/` folder (e.g. `/application/schematics/myfile.png`) from within a model?
I also have the path to the file like `schematics/myfile.png`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, `APPPATH` gives the path upto the `application` folder:

```
$path = APPPATH.'/schematics/myfile.png';
```

Comment: So using `unlink(APPPATH.'/schematics/myfile.png')` would work from within the model?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create resources folders out of application folder. Because if you use htaccess, all that you put in url is redirected how param to index.php that it will redirect to right controller.

I use it this way:

- application
- system
- css
- js
- img

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php file in the root, most useful paths are defined so that you can use them within the rest of the code.

```
FCPATH   -> '/'
BASEPATH -> '/system/'
APPPATH  -> '/application/'
```

Or maybe try

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/schematics/myfile.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unlink(APPPATH.'schematics/myfile.png');
```

Deleteing a file is as simple as calling [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink), regardless of what PHP framework you are using, but since you are using CodeIgniter, you can use the APPPATH constant.